# Windows Security and login/password WS authorization

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I need to secure access to my Web Service using both Windows Security an login/password method.

If the user is accessing the WS and not having a domain user then ask him to fill in the login and password.

Is it possible to do this with ASP.NET Membership Provider?